# Should I set PAGER environment variable, alias or symbolic link?

Tags: path, alias, pager

I noticed that when using aliases, some programs launch pager directly (either from `PATH` or through `PAGER`). I'd like to define default pager for all cases, not just when I type the command.

Should I set `PAGER` or put `pager` in path instead of defining shell alias? What is the convention for other executables like editors?

Answer (score 3):

The pager is most often executed by things outside of your shell, such as the `man` command, or various `git` subcommands, so a shell alias doesn't have the power to do anything in that majority of cases and therefore doesn't make much sense. There is a standard `$PAGER` environment variable — use it!

Alternatively, on a Debian system for system-wide configuration, try:

```
update-alternatives --config pager
```

Comment: And for editors, there's `VISUAL` and `EDITOR`.